# How can I do this::If a div has an ID I want to add some script in the body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML coding

```
<div id="name1">
</div>
```

Now if I have the ID name2, I want to add some script just before the ending body tag.

And if I change the id to name3, I want to add another script before the ending body tag.

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: `if ($("#name2").length) //do stuff`

Comment: This question does not make a lot of sense. You don't need to add script to a live document.  You should provide details on what you are trying to accomplish instead.

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve here. But anyway.

I need a little bit of context to work out what you're trying to achieve; specifically what the script is meant to be achieving.

The non-scalable approach probably would be;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($('#name1').length)
{
   $('#footer').html('name1 is on this page');
}
else if ($('#name2').length)
{
   $('#footer').html('name2 is on this page');
}
else if ($('#name3').length)
{
   $('#footer').html('name3 is on this page');
}
else 
{
   $('#footer').html('This is a very naked body.');
}

});
```